# Is it possible to send ETH to a wallet that doesn't exist?

Tags: addresses

If so what happens? Is it permanently lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to send ETH to a wallet that does not exist.

The ETH will end up in the wallet. But if no one has the private key to unlock the wallet, the ETH will end up locked in the wallet.

Not permanently lost, just locked up forever.

Here's a wallet that no one has the private key to [0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000](http://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000). Some people have sent transactions to this wallet, and some other people have mined blocks with that account being set as the coinbase (account where the mining rewards go to). 5,133.162825689 Ether locked up currently.

Comment: So, the transaction will be mined even if the wallet doesn't exist? Or does it stay in the transaction queue?

Comment: As long as it's a valid wallet address, and the transaction details are valid, it will be mined. The wallet will be created when the transaction is mined.

Comment: Where is the private key of this wallet stored? On the node that initialized this transaction?

Comment: The private key of the sending transaction is stored in the sender's wallet - this could be a node, or something like MyEtherWallet that uses the encrypted or unencrypted key to generate a signed transaction that is then transmitted to the node. The private key for the 0x0000....0000 account does not exist.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting stuff. I didn't imagine accounts could be created this way (without a corresponding private key). Although they are of no use.

Comment: Maybe easier to understand by thinking that there are no wallets that don't exist. All possible wallets already exist, just like all possible numbers already "exist". It's just that a wallet that has been explicitly "created" does have a creator, which (hopefully) made sure to keep the private key, so that they can make use of this wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible (I've tried it out on a testnet).

Transactions are essentially statements in the form of entity **A** gives **X** amount of Ether to entity **B** signed with the private key of entity **A** and verifiable using its public key derived from its address.

Anyone reading the statement can verify that it could only have been made by **A**.

If entity **B** does not have the private key for the address it has received the amount from **A**, **B** cannot make any statements w.r.t. to the balance it received as it cannot sign any transactions and thus prove their authenticity (anyone can make a statement, the signature binds a statement uniquely to a single entity).